# How can I programmatically fire a UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

`UILocalNotification` has a `.fireDate` method, that takes `NSDate`as an argument and then fires at that time. But what if I would like to fire it when something happens in my code without using `NSDate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your `UILocalNotification` instance and call that method on `UIAplication` instance `-presentLocalNotificationNow:`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:notification]
```

In SWIFT:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
```